# Accesing Salesforce partner wsdl url

Tags: wsdl

We are integrating sf wit h boomi.I have generated partner wsdl and given to boomi team but they want to access it by using url. they can not consume file.how can boomi direcly access partner wsdl?

Comment: Instead of downloading the wsdl give them the url. Right click on the partner wsdl and select copy link shortcut in google chrome.

Comment: You need to provide credentials to access wsdl. I am looking for direct access to wsdl without challenging for credentials

Answer (score 1):

Boomi has salesforce connector. Why do you want to consume partner wsdl ?

http://www.boomi.com/solutions/salesforce

Comment: Because the boomi connector can't call the getDeleted function  
It can do everything with standard objects, but if we need to get a list of the objects deleted then the standard connector won't help, we need to do it through soap WS calls

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, you need to provide credentials to access the Salesforce WSDLs.
If Boomi insists on getting the WSDL from a URL you might find it easiest to download the WSDL yourself and then host it on a file sharing site of your choice. It will still be complete with the endpoint URL from the instance that generated it.

Comment: all these file sharing sites will give link to dowload the file but not direct access to wsdl content

Comment: @crmsj Do you have your own public facing web server? You just need to host the resulting WSDL somewhere with no authentication requirement. It should work fine as a static file.